# Can I convert a custom image into grayscale?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

[This image contains my code as well as the eroor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvhVI.png)I am getting an error while trying to convert a BGR image into grayscale.

The error is described in the image and given below as well:

error: OpenCV(4.1.1) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/color.simd_helpers.hpp:92: error: (-2:Unspecified error) in function 'cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::CvtHelper, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<1, -1, -1>, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<0, 2, 5>, cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::SizePolicy::NONE>::CvtHelper(InputArray, OutputArray, int) [VScn = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<3, 4, -1>, VDcn = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<1, -1, -1>, VDepth = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::Set<0, 2, 5>, sizePolicy = cv::impl::(anonymous namespace)::SizePolicy::NONE]'

> Invalid number of channels in input image:
>       'VScn::contains(scn)'
>   where
>       'scn' is 1

Comment: Could you add your code as text to your question? That allows people to run the code themselves an increases the chance that you will get an answer to your problem.

Comment: I think this could help [Opencv toturial](https://techtutorialsx.com/2018/06/02/python-opencv-converting-an-image-to-gray-scale/)

Answer (score 1):

Your image is already greyscale, so you can't convert it to greyscale. You created it with:

```
img = np.ones((512,512))
```

which only has 2 dimensions. If it was colour it would have 3 dimensions:

```
img = np.ones((512,512,3))
```

where the additional dimension contains the 3 RGB channels.